# Understanding power method for finding dominant eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

[image]

The power method aims to find the eigenvalue with the largest magnitude. Does magnitude still have the same meaning in this context? If so, can't we tell from the outset which eigenvalue is the largest?

And for $\lambda_1^{(1)}$, they got $\frac{61}{13}$,  why isn't it $\frac{13}{61}$?

Because we have $
\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -3 \\
       6 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}5\\
       -13
\end{bmatrix}=\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}-29\\
       61 
\end{bmatrix}
$

So I set up my equations as $\lambda61=13$

Comment: It is the other way around: if $\begin{bmatrix} -5 \\ 13 \end{bmatrix}$ were actually an eigenvector then you would have $Ax_0=\lambda x_0$ which would be $\begin{bmatrix} -29 \\ 61 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} -5 \\ 13 \end{bmatrix}$. Of course this doesn't hold, but if it approximately holds then you should be able to take the ratio of one component of the new vector to the corresponding component of the old vector to approximate the eigenvalue.

Comment: Hmm, hard to self teach this topic because not very many youtube videos, and textbooks sometimes can be hard to understand.

Comment: Is this your first time through linear algebra? If not, I highly recommend Trefethen and Bau's *Numerical Linear Algebra* for this sort of thing. If so, then this is a bit rough for someone new to linear algebra.

Comment: Is the above method called the rayleigh power method? The notes I have call it the power method.

Comment: I have generally just heard it called the power method or the power iteration method. Rayleigh *quotients* are involved in a closely related method but not directly involved in this one.

Answer (score 2):

Magnitude means the same as it usually does; we just say that because if the eigenvalues are, say, $-4$ and $1$, power iteration will find $-4$, not $1$, even though $1$ is the "largest" in the usual ordering. I'm not sure I understand your question about being able to tell, because we often don't know anything about the eigenvalues in advance when using these methods.

As for it being $\frac{61}{13}$, suppose $x_1$ were exactly an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $(Ax_1)_2$ would be $\lambda (x_1)_2$ which would be $13 \lambda$. So you divide the new vector's component by the old vector's component to estimate the eigenvalue, not the other way around. (Note that this is not the only reasonable way to approximate the eigenvalue, another way would be to consider $\frac{\| x_1 \|}{\| x_0 \|}$, which would approximate $|\lambda|$.)

Comment: In regards to initial guesses, what would happen if my guess was say (1,0). Would that make it take longer to converge, or would it make my problem unsolvable? I  guess what I am asking is, how important is it to have a close or right guess?

Comment: @anna_xox If the eigenvalues have distinct magnitudes and your initial guess is not the zero vector, then power iteration converges. (However, if you start with an eigenvector of one of the smaller eigenvalues, it will converge to an eigenvalue other than the largest one.) So in your question about $(1,0)^T$ it would still work. The convergence rate can get degraded by having a bad initial guess, however.

Comment: @anna_xox A good exercise to see this would be to consider $x_0=(1+\delta,-1-2\delta)$ with the same matrix $A$, where $\delta$ is a small number. The smaller $\delta$ gets, the longer it will take to "kill off" the component in the direction of the other eigenvector. In fact you can be quite explicit about this: this is $x_0=\delta v_1+v_2$ so you will have $A^n x_0=4^n \delta v_1+1^n v_2$. You need to have $4^n \delta$ be much larger than $1$ before you will see good results.

Comment: @anna_xox I don't understand at all. Upon normalization, the vector wihch is the "state" of power iteration converges to an eigenvector of the dominant eigenvalue of the original matrix $A$. (In regular power iteration, $A$ is the only matrix involved in the first place, so I'm not sure why you say "the original matrix".)

Comment: Ok we have eigenvalues 1 and 4, but then we also found 4.002 to be an eigenvalue. So what is the meaning of this 4.002?

Comment: @anna_xox $4.002$ is just an approximation of the eigenvalue $4$ that you obtained using a few steps of power iteration. If you did another step it would get closer to $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you start with an eigenvector $x_0 = v$, and $[x_0]_k \neq 0$.

Then $x_1 = Ax_0 = \lambda x_0$ and so $\lambda = {[x_1]_k \over [x_0]_k}$.

The hope is that you start with $x_0$ having some component in the direction of the dominant eigenvector. After enough iterations, the components corresponding to the other eigenvalues fade away.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: **"The hope is that you start with $x_0$ having some component in the direction of the dominant eigenvector"** but isn't it should be random (non-negative) one? @copper.hat

Comment: @falamiw I don't know what you are asking. One way of starting the von Mises iteration is to pick some vector from some distribution, I am not sure why you say non negative, there is no need for that (both eigenvectors of the $A$ in the question must have one negative component). The only requirement for convergence is that there is a unique eigenvalue of maximum convergence.